# How to go to a new activity after login success?

Tags: php, android, mysql, kotlin

This is my LoginActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
//edittext
private var edemail: EditText? = null
private var edpassword: EditText? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    //getting it from xml
    edemail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edtemail)
    edpassword = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edtpassword)
    findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_login).setOnClickListener {
         loginfun()
//            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HelloActivity::class.java)
//            startActivity(intent)
//            finish()
    }

    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtregister).setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, RegisterActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }





}

private fun loginfun(){
//getting the record values
val email = edemail?.text.toString()
val password = edpassword?.text.toString()
var test:Boolean=false
//creating volley string request
val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, 
EndPoints.URL_GET_USER,
        Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            try {
                val obj = JSONObject(response)
                  test = obj.getBoolean("error")
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), 
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        },
        object : Response.ErrorListener {
            override fun onErrorResponse(volleyError: VolleyError) {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, volleyError.message, 
 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }) {
    @Throws(AuthFailureError::class)
    override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
        val params = HashMap<String, String>()
        params.put("email", email)
        params.put("password", password)
        return params
    }
}

 //adding request to queue
 VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
 go(test)

}
private fun go(state:Boolean)

{if(state == true){val intent = Intent(applicationContext, HelloActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish() }

}
```

}

I want to go to HelloActivity if the login is successful. Can you help me doing this?

It doesn't work for me, the problem is the value of test can not be changed in the request.

How can it be reassigned again with error `boolean` that I have got from my php file. Everything else work well.

Answer (score 0):

1- You should remove the call for `go(test)` from here:

```
//adding request to queue
 VolleySingleton.instance?.addToRequestQueue(stringRequest)
 go(test) // this line should be removed
```

2- When you get the response you should add the call after parsing the `error` value as follows:

```
Response.Listener<String> { response ->
            try {
                val obj = JSONObject(response)
                test = obj.getBoolean("error")
                go(test) // this line should be here 
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, obj.getString("message"), 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            } catch (e: JSONException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
```

Comment: could you debug and see the value of test out of this `test = obj.getBoolean("error")` ,and could you please post the json response of this request

Comment: it's in my php file I always return false ... I have corrected it .. thanks for your help